# How to fill an array using a for loop in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a while loop which I am trying to set up an array within VueJS. The hope is to have 3 objects in the array, each one created using an RNG from 4 possible choices. Right now all it's doing when I loop through them is duplicating the same object in each array slot:

```js
methods: {
    createMonster() {
      const randomValue = Math.random();
      while (this.i < 3) {
        if (randomValue < 0.35) {
          this.monster.push({
            active: true,
            type: 'Orc',
            hp: 70
          });
          this.i++;
        } else if (randomValue < 0.7) {
          this.monster.push({
            active: true,
            type: 'Gremlin',
            hp: 60
          });
          this.i++;
        } else if (randomValue < 0.9) {
          this.monster.push({
            active: true,
            type: 'Mage',
            hp: 50
          });
          this.i++;
        } else {
          this.monster.push({
            active: true,
            type: 'Knight',
            hp: 80
          });
          this.i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Move `randomValue`’s assignment down one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the random number generation inside the `while` loop. This line `const randomValue = Math.random();` should be inside the `while` loop:

```
methods: {
  createMonster() {
    while (this.i < 3) {
      let randomValue = Math.random();
      if (randomValue < 0.35) {
        this.monster.push({
          active: true,
          type: 'Orc',
          hp: 70
        });
        this.i++;
      } else if (randomValue < 0.7) {
        this.monster.push({
          active: true,
          type: 'Gremlin',
          hp: 60
        });
        this.i++;
      } else if (randomValue < 0.9) {
        this.monster.push({
          active: true,
          type: 'Mage',
          hp: 50
        });
        this.i++;
      } else {
        this.monster.push({
          active: true,
          type: 'Knight',
          hp: 80
        });
        this.i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, the random number is generated only once and execute the `while` loop that is why you get the same random value each time and hence the same object in the array.